# Jasper Reports Web Service with Dynamic Endpoint as a Datasource

Tags: web-services, jasper-reports

We want to use web service as a datasource in our Jasper Reports version 6.2. In Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2 (community) we have a Base URL defined as: https://mywebservice/location/

Content Type: GET Parameters

Name: param1, Value: $P{param1}

Our understanding is that the query generated by Jasper Reports will be: https://mywebservice/location/?param1=$P{param1}

Unfortunately the web service endpoint does not accept ?param1. Instead the URL should be: https://mywebservice/location/$P{param1}

What can be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The standard syntax for the GET parameters is always `paramName=paramValue`, in your case you shouldn't use the GET parameters

In the server URI use the static part of your URL, so: https://mywebservice/location/

Then in the query use the parameter inside the Base URL area. The base URL will be appended to the static URI to form the full URL